# Understanding Optional with Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm having trouble understanding how I should be using optional variables. Do I have to be checking for nil throughout all of my code to prevent crashes? For example, with this code

```
   let pubHead = "Publisher: "
   if let pubName : String? = self.book?.publisher {
            self.publisherLabel?.text = pubHead+pubName!
        }
```

the book.publisher variable is optional, so it may or may not be nil, when it is not nil this code works perfectly fine, the string is appended and set to the label's text. However I get the fatal error when it is nil. Do I really need to be checking for nil throughout all of my code to prevent crashes in similar cases to this one. If so, what is the proper way to check for nil?

Comment: Optionals are a basic concept in Swift. It's much more than a `if let` statement.  Please read the appropriate section in the [Swift Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explain the bug you are seeing, the `if let` construct has the following syntax

```
if let (x: Type) = (expression of Type?)
```

That means if you want to check whether `String?` is `nil`, you will have `String` on the left side (the left side is no longer an optional).

However, if you write `String?` on the left side, the expression on the right side is inferred to be `String??`.

In other words, `self.book?.publisher` is of type `String?` (`Optional<String>`) but placing it into:

```
if let pubName : String? = self.book?.publisher {
```

it will become `String??` (`Optional<Optional<String>>`).

The `if let` then correctly removes one level of optional and you will get `String?`.

Obviously, what you want is

```
if let pubname: String = self.book?.publisher
```

or let the type be inferred

```
if let pubname = self.book?.publisher
```